# International user registration via SMS

Tags: mobile, sms, registration

I've noticed a lot of mobile apps, specifically messaging apps, are switching from email verification to SMS'ed auth codes. Being based in the US, I am wondering how this works for international users. It seems illogical that users always receive an SMS from a US-based number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio Evangelist here,

We have a lot of people using [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com) for this, sending an SMS to the user with an authorisation code. I'm actually based in the UK, and I get them from all sorts of different numbers. Some companies use [short codes (4/5/6 digit numbers)](https://www.twilio.com/sms/shortcodes), some companies use a regular long code number.

Unlike the US, we have mobile number ranges in Europe, so you can tell the difference between a mobile and landline number. Although UK landline numbers can weirdly send and receive SMS...

The experience is fine - if I've just completed some action on a web page or an app, I'm expecting the SMS, and I seldom even notice the number they came from. In fact, to answer this I had to look through my received messages to see what numbers were being used!

Hope this helps.

Comment: So the sending phone number is usually/always is a short-code and not a local number?

Comment: I suspect I get about 75% from short codes. I recently had one of the smaller couriers deliver something and they used a long code number. My bank and Google use a short code. Short codes allow you to send SMS in vast quantities, so I think that's probably a key consideration.

Answer (score 0):

They probably use a company that aggregates messaging from many operators around the world.
e.g. [clickatell.com](http://www.clickatell.com), [boku.com](http://boku.com), [zong.com](http://zong.com)

But there's no reason they can't send it from the U.S only though. There is a chance that it is blocked as spam perhaps.